# SAS time informat

Tags: time, sas

I imported data from an Excel Sheet to SAS.

Data in SAS contains time in this format 0.635417 which should be 3:15 p.m. in the original Excel sheet.

It seems that 0.635417 is the percentage of the total minutes in one day. Because one day has 1440 minutes, and (0.635417*1440)/60=15.25

so the integer 15 means 15 hours (or 3 p.m.), and 0.25*60=15 minutes, so it makes sense that the time should be 3:15 p.m.

However, I cannot find an INFORMAT that will turn this value (0.635417) into the time value (3:15 p.m.) which I want.

I will be very grateful if someone can give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the SAS documentation a time value

> is a value representing the number of seconds since midnight of the
>   current day. SAS time values are between 0 and 86400.

So all you need to do ist multiply you value by 86400 than apply an format (not informat) to that variable. For example HHMM5.

```
data x;
  x=0.635417;
  y=x*86400;
  format y HHMM5.;
run;
proc print;
run;
```